# Shape mismatch concatenating GAN generator layers along channel axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I am building a tensorflow GAN with an attention mechanism that requires me to concatenate layers.

This is the relevant part of my attention mechanism

def attention_module(x, g, inter_channel):
# x - the skip connection feature map
# g - the feature map from the decoder path (previous level output)
# inter_channel - number of intermediate channels (C/2)

```
# Channel-wise concatenation of x and g
combined = layers.Concatenate()([x, g])
```

The function is applied in the Generator bit of my GAN as follows:

```
def define_generator():
input_layer = Input(shape=(256,))
num_filters = 64
latent_dim=256
skip_connections = []

x = layers.Dense(32 * 32 * 256, use_bias=False)(input_layer)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = layers.Reshape((32, 32, 256))(x)
print(x.shape)

# Encoder
for i in range(8):
    num_filters = min(num_filters * 2, 512)
    x = layers.Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    skip_connections.append(x)

# Decoder with attention
num_filters //= 2
for i in range(8):
    num_filters = max(num_filters // 2, 64)
    g = layers.Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    g = layers.BatchNormalization()(g)
    g = layers.ReLU()(g)

    x = skip_connections[-(i+1)]
    x_prime, _ = attention_module(x, g, num_filters // 2)
```

However, when I run the code I have an error as I am concatenating along the 4th dimension of my tensors but their 2nd and 3rd dimensions are different. ** input shape=[(None, 1, 1, 512), (None, 2, 2, 128)]**.

I then applied some alternatives in the following code lines before Concatenating

```
#x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='nearest')(x)
#g = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='nearest')(g)
g = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(1, 1, 512))(g)
```

This seems to fix one instance of the issue but creates a new one with Concat giving me the following error message **input_shape=[(None, 2, 2, 128), (None, 1, 1, 512)]** for the reshape operation.

I am failing to understand where the problem might be steming from, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error you are facing shows that the dimensions of your tensors are not compatible for concatenation along the fourth dimension. To resolve this, you need to ensure that the dimensions of the tensors you're concatenating are consistent.
In your case, the tensors x and g have different shapes (None, 1, 1, 512) and (None, 2, 2, 128) respectively. To concatenate them along the fourth dimension, you need to make sure that the first and second dimensions match.